# Cómo cargar el resultado en una variable y no en un div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy usando la función **load** para traer unos datos del HTML de una página que quiero pero obligadamente me estoy viendo a crear un div y no quiero hacerlo ya que tendría que crear muchos porque serían otras páginas que tendría que cargar y se hace tedioso. Hay manera de meter el resultado cargado en una variable?

```
function loading() {

let content;

$(content).load("URL", () => {

console.log("Cargado en la variable");

});

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creas el elemento usando `createElement` sin necesidad de agregarlo al HTML

```js
let content=document.createElement("p");

$(content).load("https://randomuser.me/", () => {
  console.log(content.innerHTML);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Oye disculpa, hice tal cual el ejemplo y lo que carga en el div es el código javascript de esa página, ignora todo y entrega solamente el código javascript ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal? es decir, por ejemplo si en el javascript de esa página construyo un div no inserta el  el div en el body si no que me devuelve document.createElement("div"); en cambio si realizo la carga en un div creado en html carga todo a la perfección.

Comment: prueba cambiar `content.innerText` por `content.innerHTML`